# Can I capture an object as a const when using init caputre?

Tags: c++, lambda, type-deduction

When using C++14's init capture, 'auto' type deduction rules are applied (which throws away the reference, const and volatile)

Notice here that **I'm not saying const reference**. If I wanted a const reference I can write:

```
auto lambda = [&widget = std::as_const(widget)] () {};
// C++17
```

Or I can add & to lhs cast the rhs as a const reference.

what I'm asking for is: can I write something like this?:

```
auto lambda = [const widget = widget] () {};
```

Comment: Why do you need `const widget`?  The `operator ()` of the lambda is already `const` (unless you mark it as `mutable`) so you can't change the captured by value objects inside the function.

Comment: also why would it matter if you have a `const` reference or a `const` copy? I mean if you want it `const`, there is no need to make the copy

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't see why would I need it now. Just wondering whether there is a way to do that just in case I used 'mutable' and wanted some variable to remain not modifiable.

Comment: you also wont need it later, when you can use a const reference ;)

Comment: @idclev463035818 Yes you're right. I don't think I'm gonna need it. Just wondering whether I can do something like that or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to capture an object by value and have it be `const`.  The grammar for an [`init-capture`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.prim.lambda.capture#nt:init-capture) is

```
init-capture:
    identifier initializer
    & identifier initializer
```

where [`identifier`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/lex.name#nt:identifier) is

```
identifier:
    identifier-nondigit
    identifier identifier-nondigit
    identifier digit
```

Which means you can only specify a name, without any cv-qualifers.  For a non mutable lambda this isn't an issue since the function will be `const` and you can't modify a capture by value object.

For a mutable lambda you can capture a reference to const like you do with `[&widget = std::as_const(widget)]`.  If you can't or don't want to have a reference then you need a write a const wrapper like

```
template <typename T>
class const_wrapper
{
    const T obj;
public:
    const_wrapper(T obj) : obj(obj) {}
    operator const T&() const { return obj; }
};
```

The above object is copyable, but not assignable (because of the const member) and only allows const access to the underlying type.